# How to parse google's response?

Tags: google-search

I don't know if I said it right. I am thinking of making a tool that extracts data from google searches. Say I want to get the number of pages returned for a particular query and feed that to my program/tool. How do I go about this?

Comment: I would say that depends on your how program/tool is being written. Providing some more background may yield more useful responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into the many [Google Search Apis](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/).

Answer (score 1):

From the [Google Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS):

"You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers)..."

As @BrennaSoft said, you *can* use their developer APIs.